# removed /etc/hosts on a mac and now can't sudo

Tags: sudo, hosts

I think I made a mistake by editing /etc/hosts within sublime text, because immediately afterward I was unable to run "sudo xxx".  It would ask for a password, and then never resolve once I'd typed it in.

I tried to edit /etc/hosts, but it always required sudo, which never resolved, so that didn't work.  In the end I just deleted the file, but I'm stuck now with not being able to recreate it without access to sudo.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "resolving a password"? - Hosts file are used for name resolution - i.e. converting host names to IP-addresses. You don't resolve password. The easiest way to fix your problem is to reboot the Mac into single-user mode by holding down Cmd-s during boot. From single user mode you can recreate the hosts file. You could also take out the drive and attach to a different Mac and recreate the file from there.

Comment: Easiest way is restore from backup - or in this case reinstall the OS

Comment: @jksoegaard "resolving a password" was just referencing that when I type in a password and hit submit, nothing happens.  It just hangs indefinitely.  I'll try single-user mode suggestion, thanks!

Comment: You could boot into [target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462) by holding T during boot.  Once in target disk mode you can connect your Mac to another computer using Thunderbolt, Firewire, or USB-C, and edit files on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The file /etc/hosts is in no way related to the ability to run sudo. You probably hosed your sudoers file in a previous step.

To solve your problem boot to Recovery Mode and open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities.

- Run `df` to get the name of your main system volume.
- Change your working directory to /Volumes//etc:

  ```
  cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/etc #"Macintosh HD" is just an example name here
  ```
- Copy the spare files hosts~orig and sudoers~orig (or with similar names which may exist as "backup" in /etc by default - check this with `ls`!):

  ```
  cp hosts~orig hosts
  cp -i sudoers~orig sudoers #enter yes here
  ```

  If they don't exist create the hosts file and and check your sudoers file:

  ```
  /Volumes/<name_of_main_volume>/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/<name_of_main_volume>/etc/hosts
  ```

  The content of the default hosts file is.

  ```
  ##
  # Host Database
  #
  # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
  # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
  ##
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1             localhost
  ```

  The POSIX permissions are root:wheel 644. Modify this with `chown` and `chmod` if necessary.

  /Volumes//usr/bin/nano /Volumes//etc/sudoers

  A minimal (to type less!) working sudoers file looks like this:

  ```
  Defaults    env_reset
  Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
  Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
  Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
  Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
  Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
  Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
  Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

  Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

  root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
  %admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL
  ```

  The POSIX permissions are root:wheel 440. Modify this with `chown` and `chmod` if necessary.
- Reboot your Mac by entering:

  ```
  reboot
  ```

This can also be done in single-user-mode after mounting the root volume *rw*.

---

After regaining the ability to run sudo, either extract it from the macOS installer app with Pacifist or from a backup or modify it yourself with `visuso`. The default content is:

```
#
# Sample /etc/sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

##
# Override built-in defaults
##
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

##
# User alias specification
##
# User_Alias    FULLTIMERS = millert, mikef, dowdy

##
# Runas alias specification
##
# Runas_Alias   OP = root, operator

##
# Host alias specification
##
# Host_Alias    CUNETS = 128.138.0.0/255.255.0.0
# Host_Alias    CSNETS = 128.138.243.0, 128.138.204.0/24, 128.138.242.0
# Host_Alias    SERVERS = master, mail, www, ns
# Host_Alias    CDROM = orion, perseus, hercules

##
# Cmnd alias specification
##
# Cmnd_Alias    PAGERS = /usr/bin/more, /usr/bin/pg, /usr/bin/less

##
# User specification
##

# root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL

## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: You said, "Copy the spare files hosts~orig and shudders~orig:", where are these "spare files" coming from? They don't exist in my 10.12.3 build.

Comment: They don't exist in my macOS 10.12.3 `/etc` directory.

Comment: @user3439894 You are right. Obviously a strange coincidence that both files exist in my install

Comment: @klanomath On my current clean install, there are a lot of `~orig` and `~previous` files.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` and `sudo` are actually very much related: https://superuser.com/questions/429790/sudo-command-trying-to-search-for-hostname#429890

Answer (score 0):

While you are booted normally to your regular account, do the following in Terminal:

```
touch sudoers.ori hosts.ori
open -e sudoers.ori hosts.ori
```

- Note: This assumes you're in your Home directory when executing these commands.

In the `hosts.ori` file, copy and paste the following:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Then save and close the `hosts.ori` file.

In the `sudoers.ori` file, copy and paste the following:

```
#
# Sample /etc/sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

##
# Override built-in defaults
##
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

##
# User alias specification
##
# User_Alias    FULLTIMERS = millert, mikef, dowdy

##
# Runas alias specification
##
# Runas_Alias   OP = root, operator

##
# Host alias specification
##
# Host_Alias    CUNETS = 128.138.0.0/255.255.0.0
# Host_Alias    CSNETS = 128.138.243.0, 128.138.204.0/24, 128.138.242.0
# Host_Alias    SERVERS = master, mail, www, ns
# Host_Alias    CDROM = orion, perseus, hercules

##
# Cmnd alias specification
##
# Cmnd_Alias    PAGERS = /usr/bin/more, /usr/bin/pg, /usr/bin/less

##
# User specification
##

# root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL

## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

Then save and close the `sudoers.ori` file.

Now from the Recovery HD boot in Terminal, do the following:

```
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/etc
cp /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/*/hosts.ori hosts
cp /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/*/sudoers.ori sudoers
chown root:wheel hosts
chown root:wheel sudoers
chmod 0644 hosts
chmod 440 sudoers
reboot
```

- Note: `Macintosh HD` is the default name, however if you've changed it for whatever reason, change it appropriately in the command line.